# Bullet physics source code not building in x86 - wrong preprocessor directives in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, assert, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to build Bullet Physics source code. None of their cmake stuff works, so I just copied the Bullet source files straight into my visual studio project and built it directly. However, only the 64 bit version will build. When I try to build in 32 bit, it gives a bunch of errors starting with "E2474 user-defined literal operator not found" - which seems to come from definition of btAssert in btScalar.h

My project must be missing some preprocessor directive or setting or something. If anyone can take a look at these definitions and see what settings need to be changed in my Visual Studio 2017 project, that would be amazing. Please let me know, thanks.

project link:
https://github.com/mister51213/BulletSetupTest/tree/master/BulletPhysicsTest1

code:

```
#ifdef BT_DEBUG
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        #include <stdio.h>
        #define btAssert(x) { if(!(x)){printf("Assert "__FILE__ ":%u ("#x")\n", __LINE__);__debugbreak();   }}
        //#define btAssert(x)

    #else//_MSC_VER
        #include <assert.h>
        #define btAssert assert
    #endif//_MSC_VER
#else
        #define btAssert(x)
        //#define btAssert(x) { if(!(x)){printf("Assert "__FILE__ ":%u ("#x")\n", __LINE__);__debugbreak(); }}

#endif
        //btFullAssert is optional, slows down a lot
        #define btFullAssert(x)

        #define btLikely(_c)  _c
        #define btUnlikely(_c) _c
#else
```

Answer (score 1):

Macro expansions without a space between a string literal and the next element, like

```
"Assert "__FILE__
```

runs into problems with the rules for [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), which reserves this format.

This happened already in C++11.

The simple solution is to just add a space between the string literal and the next element:

```
"Assert "  __FILE__
---------^
```

For more examples see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Notes